# How to save state between different pdb(pp) sessions?

Tags: python, pdb

I use `pdbpp` to debug programs. I wonder if it is possible to save and restore `pdbpp`'s (or `pdb`'s) state between different sessions.

What I mean by this is that I want to preserve all my breakpoints, aliases, display lists etc. between independent invocations of the debugger process.

I am aware that state is preserved within single debugger process. But what if I quit debugger and start it again. Is that possible to restore the state?

Answer (score 2):

From [`pdb`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) documentation:

> If a file .pdbrc exists in the user’s home directory or in the current directory, it is read in and executed as if it had been typed at the debugger prompt. This is particularly useful for aliases. If both files exist, the one in the home directory is read first and aliases defined there can be overridden by the local file.

From here one can conclude that it is often useful to have `~/.pdbrc` file where one can define general aliases, commands and display lists.

Breakpoints should probably be defined in a local `.pdbrc` file, as they are very program specific.

In the case of `pdbpp` we can also have `~/.pdbrc.py`, where we can put arbitrary Python code, for example, to customize debugger configuration, configure history etc.